# Android Studio for Mac - does not include sdk, sdk no longer available as standalone download

Tags: android, android-studio

I've downloaded the Android Studio for Mac package from [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#features) multiple times today. The SDK is not included.

- on open Studio app, asks for SDK path
- there is no SDK path, not even at /Users/(me)/Applications/Android/

In fact, the directory "Android" is not created.

Links that used to go to standalone SDK downloads now also redirect to the same link - for Studio.

How can I get the SDK?

Comment: The sdk should be installed during install process.

Comment: it's not - hence my question here :(

Comment: There is many sources on "how to install android studio" please follow one of them, also there is one in stackOverFlow Documentation.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not asking you where you want to install the Android SDK? You might want to edit your question and post a screenshot of the dialog where you are stuck.

Comment: When you first-time download android studio package then after SDK is auto set the path of /Users/<username>/Library/Android/SDK or you can Android Studio->Preferences->Appeareance & Behavior->System Settings->Android SDK-> here Android SDK Location but in your case, it missing our other path so uninstall studio and reinstall

Comment: Uninstall and re-install did not resolve the issue. The SDK just plain is not included, and all old links to the standalone SDK now redirect to the Studio installer.  I gave up on this and asked another dev to zip and send me the SDK. StackOverflow used to provide answers but here all that happened were people told me to try everything I had already tried.

Answer (score -1):

Android sdk is separately available to download from website
Install it and then limk to you android studio.

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Comment: I do not know what you are referring to. If you are referring to the "Get just the command line tools" section, please note that it says "These tools are included in Android Studio."

Comment: This is a link to Studio. SDK is not available here.

Comment: The command line tools are usually the zip file containing the sdk, if your installation for some reason failed to install sdk you can do it manually, that's what I was referring to

Comment: @Deborah sdk links are below studio downloads

Comment: There are only command line tools links, not sdk links.The command line tools zip folder, extracted, does not contain an sdk folder.